# Show that any non-negative rational integer may be written as the sum of two squares if it is of the form....

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that any non-negative rational integer may be written as the sum of two squares if it is of the form $$2^ip_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_m^{k_m}q_1^{2j_1}q_2^{2j_2}\cdots q_n^{2j_n}$$ where the $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_m$ are all primes congruent to $1\bmod 4$, the $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n$ are all primes congruent to $3\bmod 4$ and $i,k_1,k_2,\dots,k_m,j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n$ are all non-negative integers.

I am completely blank on how to form a solution, so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First show that all the $p_i$ can be so written, then that all the $q_j^2$ can be so written (note that these are all $\equiv 1\mod{4}$), then apply [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity).

Comment: Hint: $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ together with $p\nmid a$ or $p\nmid b$ gives that $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$, hence $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I am still very confused on how to apply your hints.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/4400twosquares.pdf); it's a very clear exposition of the theorem.

Comment: I am still unsure on how to apply this to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all a rather trivial point: a square is a sum of two squares (of which usually one will need to be $0^2$)

now you need a lemma: if $a$ is a sum of two squares and $b$ is a sum of two squares, then the product $ab$ is also a sum of two squares.

this is easy to see in terms of the multiplication of two Gaussian integers:

$$
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=|a+ib|^2|c+id|^2=|(a+ib)(c+id)|^2=|(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)|^2=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2
$$

since $2=1^2+1^2$ the lemma implies any power of two is a sum of two squares.

a well-known theorem tells us that any prime of the form $4n+1$ is the sum of two squares, so the lemma implies that any product of such primes $p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_m^{k_m}$ is a sum of two squares.

finally to multiply a sum of two squares by a square (of the form $q_1^{2j_1}q_2^{2j_2}\cdots q_n^{2j_n}$) is again a sum of two squares.

the proof of the theorem about primes of the form $4n+1$ is a fairly easy consequence of two basic results: Wilson's theorem and the fact that the Gaussian integers are a Euclidean ring and therefore are a  Unique Factorization Domain. Wilson's theorem is a simple exercise in modular arithmetic. To demonstrate a division algorithm for the Gaussian integers is a little more technical but of an elementary nature.

Comment: @OP In case it wasn't obvious, this proof is the same as mine, and the key step (primes of the form $4n+1$ are sums of two squares) is also not proven here.

Comment: I understand this, and I believe I will be able to finish the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity), the product of two sums of two squares is a sum of two squares, so it suffices to prove that $2$, each $p_i$, and each $q_i^2$ is a sum of two squares. Obviously $q_i^2=q_i^2+0^2$ is a sum of two squares, and $2=1^2+1^2$.

Thus we are reduced to the case of proving that if $p\equiv 1\pmod4$ is a prime number, then $p$ is a sum of two squares. This is not a simple theorem; an exposition can be found at Theorem 4 [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400twosquares.pdf).

---

Although the original theorem doesn't say it, the statement is a bit complicated if the only goal is the forward direction. In fact, the stated form covers *all* numbers that are sums of two squares. To see this, given $n$ which is a sum of two squares, take its prime factorization and partition the primes into $2$, $p_i\equiv1$, and $q_i\equiv3\pmod 4$. Then we need only prove that the exponent of each $q_i$ is even, and we may assume additionally that all smaller sums of two squares are of the given form.

If $q_i\mid n=a^2+b^2$, then in $\Bbb Z[i]$ we have $q_i\mid(a-bi)(a+bi)$, so $q_i\mid a-bi$ or $q_i\mid a+bi$, and in both cases $q_i\mid a$ and $q_i\mid b$. Then $q_i^2\mid a^2+b^2=n$, so $$n/q_i^2=2^ip_1^{k_1}\cdots p_m^{k_m}q_1^{j_1}\cdots q_i^{2j_i}\cdots q_n^{2j_n},$$ and then $$n=2^ip_1^{k_1}\cdots p_m^{k_m}q_1^{2j_1}\cdots q_i^{2(j_i+1)}\cdots q_n^{2j_n}.$$

Comment: So there is still another case to prove to achieve a solution?

Comment: I reduced the problem to a known special case which is covered in many books. Just look up "the two-square theorem" and you'll find it (or click the link). Yes, you're going to need some legwork if you are trying to use this on your homework. I'm not here to do your work for you.